# Update state for every network call in Array

Tags: java, reactjs

[image]I have an array of object and for each object I sent axios network request. I have updatedTableData in state variable and for each object I want to update my state variable , in which before request for each array of object I will push object in updateTableData with key status:"uploading" and on successful response I want to update this object to status: 'successfully uploaded' and status: 'failed' on failed response.How do I setState updateTableData so that for each object I get corresponding status: 'loading', 'success' or 'failed'. In below code when i console log(updatedTableData) is get correct array but It doesn't show updated value in dom element. Attach Image shows what I want to achieve

```
const { selectedFiles } = this.state
    const filteredFileList = []
    selectedFiles.forEach((file) => {
      if (!file.checked) {
        filteredFileList.push({ ...file })
      } else {
        filteredFileList.push({
          ...file,
          status: 'Uploading',
          statusIcon: 'loading'
        })
      }
    })
    console.log(selectedFiles, filteredFileList)
    this.setState({ updatedTableData: filteredFileList })
    selectedFiles.forEach((file) => {
      if (file.checked) {
        const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('file', file.originFileObj)
        axios.post('http://localhost:8004/builder/fileupload/single', formData,
          {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
              userid: '5d2dc8b5b3ede2187d00af90'
            }
          },
        ).then(() => {
          const elementsIndex = filteredFileList.findIndex(element => element.uid === file.uid)
          filteredFileList[elementsIndex] = { ...filteredFileList[elementsIndex],
            status: 'SuccessFully Uploaded',
            statusIcon: 'check-circle' }
          this.setState({ updatedTableData: filteredFileList })
        }).catch(() => {
          const elementsIndex = filteredFileList.findIndex(element => element.uid === file.uid)
          filteredFileList[elementsIndex] = { ...filteredFileList[elementsIndex],
            status: 'failed',
            statusIcon: 'close-circle' }
          this.setState({ updatedTableData: filteredFileList })
        })
      }
    })
    // setTimeout(() => {
    //   this.setState({ updatedTableData: filteredFileList2.sort((a, b) => a.key - b.key) })
    // }, 1000)
    //this.setState({ updatedTableData: filteredFileList })
    console.log(filteredFileList)
```

Comment: You are not logging `updatedTableData` but `filteredFileList` (which is not state)

Comment: I'm logging updatedTableData in render() function .

Comment: You did not post your render function